# Expression pour l'acte de laisser un objet dans la rue pour qu'un inconnu le prenne

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, culture

J'ai vu cela plusieurs fois dans certaines grandes villes françaises: au lieu d'aller a la déchetterie pour se débarrasser d'objets encombrants, certaines personnes les laissent dans la rue, sachant que d'autres (étudiants, revendeurs, biffins, gens du voyage,...) les récupèreront rapidement.

C'est illégal mais plutôt efficace. Certains étudiants que je connais ont recupéré leur canapé, table et chaises de cette façon. Mon vieux frigo n'a pas passé plus d'une nuit dehors.

J'ai vu plusieurs fois des expressions pour designer cette pratique. Mais impossible de m'en rappeler. Ces expressions etaient probablement de l'argot, quelquechose d'imagé mais pas vulgaire, si ma memoire est bonne.

Quelqu'un connait-il le nom de cette pratique?

Answer (score 4):

Du point de vue des autorités locales ou de la police chargés de réprimer cet usage, on trouvera l'expression "dépôt clandestin" ou "dépôt sauvage", mais c'est un terme plutôt administratif ou juridique.

Comment: Ce n'est pas faux, mais je cherche plutot une expression du point de vue de ceux qui abandonne un objet, ou de ceux qui le recupere.

Comment: Une initiative locale pas loin de chez moi utilise le terme "donnerie", mais c'est un endroit désigné et aménagé pour cela, où on peut laisser les objets dont on veut se débarrasser, à jours et heures fixes. Peut-être ce même terme est-il aussi utilisé pour des abandons "sauvages" ?

Answer (score 2):

Chez moi on utilise l'expression "mettre aux encombrants" ou "laisser aux encombrants"

Généralement on dit ça les jours où les encombrants (les employés chargés de ramasser les objets encombrants) passent.

Comment: Les encombrants sont un service municipal de ramassage des ordures volumineuses. La, je parle d'une pratique officieuse et illegale.

Comment: @Taladris De facto, des brocanteurs et autre passent avant les services municipaux. Le savoir vivre impose de "balancer" ton frigo le jour des encombrant pour être sûr qu'il est ramassé in fine

Answer (score 1):

Je ne suis pas certain que ça représente exactement cette situation mais ce qui pourrais se dire:

- Je le laisse au suivant
- Je le donne au suivant

Answer (score 1):

Pas vraiment de l’argot (plutôt l’extension d’une expression des sujets animés aux biens inanimés), mais dans son sens de « abandonner », peut-être la phrase « [laisser les meubles/biens] [**sur le carreau**](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/sur-le-carreau.php) » est parmi les expressions que vous avez vu pour cette pratique. (*expressio.fr*)

Pour un exemple de son emploi au Québec, voyez page 2 en haut à gauche du [*Bulletin Municipal* de la Ville d’Asbestos](http://ville.asbestos.qc.ca/data/files/Bulletin/Bulletin_municipal_du_20_mai_2010.pdf).

Comment: J'ai vu le bulletin et ça m'a un peu surpris comme emploi, ça veut essentiellement dire sur le pavé, dans la rue finalement. Un truc vraiment familier au Québec c'est je crois « sur le bord du chemin », mais ça non plus ça ne contient pas l'idée de laisser manifestement à l'autre etc. Parfois on a ce genre de pratique en marketing comme ds. un téléphone public sur un rebord etc. on peut trouver parfois de petits cartons avec une pub dessus, genre un _rave_ ou qqc. du genre. Une forme de _marketing sauvage_, mais parfois on a ça avec un magazine, une forme d'altruisme... ? Merci !

Answer (score 1):

Je ne crois pas qu'il y ait une expression toute faite d'usage général et ayant spécifiquement ce sens.

Une façon simple et compréhensible : "Laisser sur le trottoir".

Cela ne dit pas explicitement "pour qu'un inconnu le prenne", mais les gens le font-ils vraiment pour cela, ou bien seulement pour se débarrasser des objets sans s'embêter à regarder le calendrier du service de encombrants?

Answer (score 0):

Pour accompagner cette désinvolture, on peut dire :
Mon vieux canapé ? Je l'ai balancé sur le trottoir !